# How would I differentiate with respect to x equations with Euler's number in them?

Tags: calculus

I understand how to differentiate but am not sure as to how to do it with Euler's number.

> Differentiate with respect to $x$:
>
> $$y=e^{x^3+2}$$

Comment: $e^x$ is called the exponential function. It is without doubt the most important function in mathematics and science. If you are already studying differentiation, then it's crucial that you learn the properties of this function and various definition of it

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Recall that by chain rule

$$f(x)=e^{g(x)}\implies f'(x)=g'(x)\cdot e^{g(x)}$$

Comment: thanks! @gimusi

Comment: @wendy Youa re welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2):

Chain rule states: $\frac {d}{dx}f(g(x))=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$, then $$(e^{x^3+2})'=e^{x^3+2}\cdot 3x^2$$

Comment: thanks for your explanation, @Bertrand Wittgenstein's Ghost !

Comment: @wendy You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If $y=e^x$ then $y'=e^x=y$ (we can also write $\frac {dy}{dx}$ instead of $y'$, they are different notations for the same thing). This relationship can be used in the chain rule so, for example if $y=e^{ax}$ then $y'=(ax)'e^{ax}=ae^{ax}$, and I use this with $a=-1$ below.

---

The importance of the exponential function comes in part because it is the basic solution to $y'=y$. Indeed if $y'=y$ then consider $z=ye^{-x}$, which we can differentiate using the chain rule and product rule to give $$z'=y'e^{-x}-ye^{-x}=0$$ and since the derivative of $z$ is zero we have $z=C$ so that $ye^{-x}=C$ and $y=Ce^x$, where $C$ is any constant.

Comment: thank you so much @Mark Bennet